# action chaining error:There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login.action] associated with context path [/chaining]

Tags: struts2, chaining, action-mapping

my task is on struts2 action chaining,my program name is `chaining` ,i am using correct syntax,but it is not working.

struts.xml

```
<action name="register" class="RegisterAction"> 
    <result name="success" type="chain">login.action</result>    
</action>
<action name="login" class="LoginAction" >
    <result name="success">/login.jsp</result>  
</action>
```

RegisterAction.java

```
public class RegisterAction {

    public String execute() {
        return "success";             
    }
}
```

LoginAction.java

```
public class LoginAction {

    public String execute() {
        return "success";
    }
}
```

but when i run program,it gives the following error occurs

> There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [login.action] associated with context path [/chaining].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the suffix from your chained Action name, from this

```
<result name="success" type="chain">login.action</result>
```

to this

```
<result name="success" type="chain">login</result>
```

Note that Action Chaining is not recommended, Redirect Action or some other ways should be preferred.

From [the official documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/action-chaining.html):

> **Don't Try This at Home**
> As a rule, Action Chaining is not recommended. First explore other options, such as the Redirect After Post technique.

Take a look at this answer too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4761955/1654265