# Struts2 Pass Action Bean from One action to other Action in type chain

Tags: struts2

I have two Struts2 actions and both actions are chained so that flow sequence with be
  **action1 ---> action2 ---> display.jsp**

```
    class Action1 extends ActionSupport
    {


      public String display()
      {
         Student stud = new Student();
         stud.setName("I am from Action1");

         //what should be done here so that I can get stud in another action via chain   
         return "success";

      }


    }

   class Action2 extends ActionSupport
    {
      private Student stud;
      //getter/setter

      public String display()
      {
         Sting name = stud.getName();//getting NULL here
         return "success";

      }


    }
```

I want to pass stud object from one action to another via chain.
 My strut2.xml setting is as below

```
<action name="action1" class="com.internet.Action1" method="display">
    <result name="success" type="chain">action2</result>
 </action>

  action name="action2" class="com.internet.Action2" method="display">
    <result name="success" type="tiles">MyDiplayPage</result>
 </action>
```

I have worked in spring 3.0 and I am uncomfortable with struts2 and trying to acquire comfort in that.. please help me to sort out the issue.

Comment: Usage of `chain` is discouraged. Why do you need it?

Comment: okey then could you tell me how to do via redirectAction

Comment: You mean pass the object? Store it somewhere e.g. session.

Comment: why usage of chain is discouraged?

Comment: See https://struts.apache.org/docs/action-chaining.html and http://stackoverflow.com/q/4756097/1700321.

Comment: Why you uncomfortable with struts2? You can use spring 3.0 (but without MVC) along with struts2 and it double the flexibility to build a frontend/backend  compared to spring. So you have to work with different things in struts2, that aren't available in spring.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Chaining Interceptor` is what you are [looking for](https://struts.apache.org/docs/action-chaining.html):

> If you need to copy the properties from your previous Actions in the
>   chain to the current action, you should apply the Chaining
>   Interceptor. The Interceptor will copy the original parameters from
>   the request, and the ValueStack is passed in to the target Action. The
>   source Action is remembered by the ValueStack, allowing the target
>   Action to access the properties of the preceding Action(s) using the
>   ValueStack, and also makes these properties available to the final
>   result of the chain, such as the JSP or Velocity page.

You can access whatever you want from the `Value Stack`. Just push the Bean you want from one Action to it's Value Stack:

```
Map<String, Object> myValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
myValues.put("key", myBean);
ActionContext.getContext().getValueStack().push(myValues);
```

Passing some values it's ok, but take care that excesive needing of passing information from one Action to another one, maybe could be a symptom that you need to re-think your Action's scope:

> All the core logic should be pushed back to a support class or a
>   business facade, so that Actions only call methods. Actions are best
>   used as adapters, rather than as a class where coding logic is
>   defined.

Comment: The last statement contradicts with the first one. Manipulating the value stack manually is not a good practice because it might break a functionality already exposed by the application.